# Linear transformation from one vector to another

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A base-motif fractal is a type of fractal created by having a base(starting) pattern and a motif one. This example pattern repeated infinite times would generate the koch curve:

**[Watch example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLH7H.png), StackExchange won't let me upload any image because of my low reputation.**

In this example, the **blue** one is the base. The **red** one is the motif. And the **green** one is the mapped motif into the base, generated by a linear transformation(I think).

---

My first thought was: "Well, there must be a matrix that maps $Q_1$ into $P_1=Q_1'$, $Q_3$ into $Q_3'$ and $Q_5$ into $P_2=Q_5'$"; in other words, there must be some matrix that transforms $\vec{Q_1Q_5}$ into $\vec{P_1P_2}$, and then apply that matrix to all points of the motif.

I started to write down the system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} Q_{1x} \\ Q_{1y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} P_{1x} \\ P_{1y} \end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} Q_{5x} \\ Q_{5y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} P_{2x} \\ P_{2y} \end{bmatrix}
\end{cases}
$$

I started to work that by hand, but Mathematica told me that the answer for $a$ is:

$$a= \dfrac{P_{2x}Q_{1y}-P_{1x}Q_{5y}}{Q_{1y}Q_{5x}-Q_{1x}Q_{5y}}$$

The answers for b, c, d are very similar to this one, they all have the same denominator.

---

My question is: It returns an error when $Q_{1y}Q_{5x}-Q_{1x}Q_{5y}=0$, or $\dfrac{Q_{1x}}{Q_{1y}}=\dfrac{Q_{5x}}{Q_{5y}}$, because division by zero.

That means that if $Q_1=[1,1]$ and $Q_5=[3,3]$ there will be some division by zero in either $a, b, c$ or $d$, and I don't think that's logical. Am I missing something somewhere? Should I approach this problem from another angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because $Q_1$ and $Q_5$ in that case are on the same line from the origin, so are linearly dependent. Then $Q_5=\lambda Q_1$ and $Q_5'=\lambda Q_1'$, that is, the transformation of $Q_1$ fixes the transformation of $Q_5$. So the second equation provides no new information, which is why it can't be solved.

To fix this, just use two points that aren't on the same line from the origin, instead of $Q_1$ and $Q_5$. ($Q_1$ and $Q_3$, for instance.)